# Native vs Open API SalesForce App

Tags: salesforce, native

What are the differences between a native SalesForce app and an app that is compatible with SalesForce?

Comment: Could you extend your question? it is not clear for me your concepts of native salesforce app and app compatible.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. Where did you get the concepts of "native" and "compatible"? There a lot of different options for creating applications related to SFDC with different levels of "nativeness".

Comment: 'Native' is a term devised by SalesForce itself.  Some apps are considered 'native' to the ecosystem because they were built on the SalesForce platform.  There are other software which are built on its own foundations but which can interact dynamically with SalesForce.  Acuariano, your question suggests you're not very familiar with SalesForce's ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be correct in all cases. A native app uses the Salesforce database. A compatible app is integrated with Salesforce, and some data/code/etc. may not exist exclusively on the Salesforce platform for compatible apps.